# how do you find the web address of the server that connects your router to the internet?

Tags: routes, dhcp

This may belong somewhere else, but I can't see where, so I'll ask it here.

I live in a community that "provides" internet service to homeowners. So, in essence, the community has a fixed IP address, then builds out a sub-network by masking, then the router does the same.  In essence, the whole community shares an IP address, but the community service puts in a router from the ISP to all homes, and each home's router sees a different gateway because of this nesting of routers.

So, when I look at my router, the address of my devices are all like 169.128.50.12.   but when I look at my gateway, it has an address like 169.128.50.01.  Presumably, some other homeowner has a gateway that is at 169.128.51.01, or some such.

Today I got an alert from Google that someone in my physical area was blocked from logging in, even though they knew my account name and password.  I am trying to figure out if it is authentic, but it may simply be that the whole community has an IP address to the ISP of, say, 12.62.126.73 (the sort of address reported in the alert).

In a nested internet architecture such as that, how can one tell what the IP address of the community's gateway is?  I can't see it on my router, because all it knows (via the mask and DHCP assignment) is that it's location on the local internet is 129.168.50.01.  But that is its sub-net address.

Is there a clever way to use ping or traceroute to figure out the whole community's IP address is?  I suspect one of my own devices tried to log in, but Google thought some unknown IP address was trying to infiltrate, because what it saw was the community IP address.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - probably [sf]

Answer (score 0):

If on Windows, get a DOS screen (type 'run' in the search box at lower left).  then type:

```
ipconfig
```

It will give you a unix-based network dump.

To see how many hops and which ones to (say) www.google.com, type:

```
'ping www.google.com'
```

And, to see the routing, type 'tracert www.google.com'